# view Pager not showing contents

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am new to android and I am having problem viewing my view contents in view pager layout. the following is my activity and adapter together on the same file and the the ViewPager xml and the details.
**my detail.xml**

```
     <FrameLayout 
                     android:id="@+id/detailsScrollView"
                      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="match_parent"
                       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">  



                 <GridLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
                     android:paddingTop="70dp">

             <TextView
          android:id="@+id/nameLabelTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactLabelTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_row="0"
          android:text="@string/label_name"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/nameTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:layout_row="0"/>

           <TextView
          android:id="@+id/phoneLabelTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactLabelTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_row="1"
          android:text="@string/label_phone"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/phoneTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:layout_row="1"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/emailLabelTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactLabelTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_row="2"
          android:text="@string/label_email"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/emailTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:layout_row="2"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/streetLabelTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactLabelTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_row="3"
          android:text="@string/label_street"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/streetTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:layout_row="3"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/cityLabelTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactLabelTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_row="4"
          android:text="@string/label_city"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/cityTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:layout_row="4"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/stateLabelTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactLabelTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_row="5"
          android:text="@string/label_state"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/stateTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:layout_row="5"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/zipLabelTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactLabelTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:layout_row="6"
          android:text="@string/label_zip"/>

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/zipTextView1"
          style="@style/ContactTextView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:layout_row="6"/>
   </GridLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

My **viewPager.xml** file has the following contents

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/addEdit">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/slide"
    android:visibility="visible">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

My activity class has the following codes and also contain the adapter class
and the code is as follows

```
        public class AddEdit extends AppCompatActivity

               {





              ViewPager mViewPager;
              pageViewAdapter1 slider;



              List<Info> informatn = new ArrayList<>();

             @Override
             protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
               {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit);
           Toolbar tool=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar1);
          mViewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.slide);
           slider=new pageViewAdapter1(this);
          mViewPager.setAdapter(slider);
          setSupportActionBar(tool);


          }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater findMenuItems = getMenuInflater();
            findMenuItems.inflate(R.menu.fragment_details_menu, menu);
            return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_delete:
                    Toast.makeText(AddEdit.this,"delete 
          ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.action_edit:
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


}


   public class pageViewAdapter1 extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;

    public pageViewAdapter1(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return informatn.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(View)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private TextView nameTextView; // displays contact's name
    private TextView phoneTextView; // displays contact's phone
    private TextView emailTextView; // displays contact's email
    private TextView streetTextView; // displays contact's street
    private TextView cityTextView; // displays contact's city
    private TextView stateTextView; // displays contact's state
    private TextView zipTextView; // displays contact's zip

        mInflater=(LayoutInflater) 
   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail,container,false);

        // get the EditTexts
        nameTextView = (TextView) 
   item_view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView1);
        phoneTextView = (TextView) 
         item_view.findViewById(R.id.phoneTextView1);
        emailTextView = (TextView) 
         item_view.findViewById(R.id.emailTextView1);
        streetTextView = (TextView) 
        item_view.findViewById(R.id.streetTextView1);
        cityTextView = (TextView) 
         item_view.findViewById(R.id.cityTextView1);
        stateTextView = (TextView) 
       item_view.findViewById(R.id.stateTextView1);
        zipTextView = (TextView) item_view.findViewById(R.id.zipTextView1);

        informatn=getInfos();

        nameTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).name);
        phoneTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).phone);
        emailTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).eamil);
        streetTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).street);
        cityTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).City);
        stateTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).state);
        zipTextView.setText(informatn.get(position).zip);


        container.addView(item_view);

        return item_view;


          }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object 
         object) {
        container.removeView((FrameLayout)object);
       }
        }

         }
```

Could some one tell me why I don't see widgets in detail.xml after I inflated them.Please try to understand that I am just beginner trying to learn. Thank you

Comment: update the instantiateItem function is not being treigger

Comment: The `PagerAdapter`'s `getCount()` method is returning `informatn.size()`. The `informatn` `ArrayList` is empty, as you only seem to populate it in `instantiateItem()`, which is not going to be called if `getCount()` returns `0`. You need to populate `informatn` somewhere else; e.g., before you set the `PagerAdapter` on the `ViewPager`.